# Использование gif анимации в WPF

Tags: wpf, c#

Подскажите, как можно реализовать отображение gif анимации в wfp?

Answer (score 2):

На codeproject есть неплохая [статья](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/animatedgifinwpf.aspx) по этому поводу